# i want to download file from google drive using Drive Api

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, google-apis-explorer

in this code :

```
file_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M'
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

I don't know how to get file_id , I was getting file_id while uploading but now I am not able to figure out how to get file_id of the file which is present on Google Drive.

Ex. if my uploaded file has name A001002.pdf , how can i get file id for this file. 
there is some reference online which i am not able to understand.

link: [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list)

any help?

Answer (score 2):

The file.list method contains a q paramater which is used for searching

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name+%3D+'hello'&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

**Python Guess**

```
"""
Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.

Creates a Drive v3 API service and prints the names and ids of the last 10 files
the user has access to.
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Drive v3 API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Drive v3 API
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="*").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Note this example does not show how to add the additional parameter i am still Googling that but i am not a python dev you may know more about how to do that than me.

Comment: i am able to get file id but those files are not visible on the drive , are my upload going to a folder which is hidden etc.                                                    
{u'id': u'1DXB8jEKibjK_R5wdxCOLdHH7wVrIU1Vq', u'name': u'abcd'}
} like these but file with name "abcd" which i uploaded is not visible

Comment: are you using a service account for authentication.  If so you are probably uploading on its account.   If not you may want to reauthencate your code as you are logged into the wrong account.

Comment: try doing an https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get call it will tell you who are you are logged in as.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation, there is one more alternative. In case you do not need to programmatically get the fileID you can just open the file in google docs from the browser and the ID is shown in the URL.

Comment: Please make your answer more substantial; an existing answer can serve as an inspiration.