# Python3 script to download file from Google drive

Tags: python-3.x, download, google-drive-api

I have an issue using python script to download file from google drive. I have researched a bit from this forum and found the following snippet useful. I do get a downloaded file every time I run the script (but only 64 Kb size and error while opening the file). **Update**: It turns out that the issue is in the user permission for the file.If I use the option from restricted access to anyone's access who has the link to download the file, this snippet works fine. Now my next problem is how I can use the authentication for downloading the file?  Can anyone please help me to solve this issue? thanks!

```
import requests

def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    def get_confirm_token(response):
        for key, value in response.cookies.items():
            if key.startswith('download_warning'):
                return value

    return None

def save_response_content(response, destination):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

session = requests.Session()

response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id }, stream = True)
token = get_confirm_token(response)

if token:
    params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
    response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)

save_response_content(response, destination)    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) is not 3:
        print "Usage: python google_drive.py drive_file_id 
        destination_file_path"
    else:
    # TAKE ID FROM SHAREABLE LINK
        file_id = sys.argv[1]
    # DESTINATION FILE ON YOUR DISK
        destination = sys.argv[2]
        download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination)
```

Comment: Have you checked this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790212/i-want-to-download-file-from-google-drive-using-drive-api)?

Comment: I have checked that post, but no acceptable solution yet.